# Question about gcd (greatest-common-divisor)

Tags: gcd-and-lcm

I have this question about gcd and I have doubts:

"The gcd between two numbers is 48 and the largest number is 384. What is the other number?"

I thought that the missing number must be a multiple of 48 as well, but I can't find a way to find that number.

Thanks.

Comment: Knowing that it is a multiple of $48$, there aren't many candidates to check (since it must be less than $384$). That said, there are quite a number of possible solutions that are equally valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other number is of the form $48k$ with $\gcd(k,\tfrac{384}{48})=1$. Given that $384$ is the largest of the two, we have $k\leq\tfrac{384}{48}=8$. This leaves $k=1,3,5,7$, assuming $k$ is positive, yielding $4$ solutions.

Comment: Thank you! Note: k = 3 is also a valid solution

Comment: It should be  " $\gcd(k,\frac{384}{48})=1$ " .

Comment: @orangeskid You are right, of course. I have corrected the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't recommend this method in general, but maybe it gives you some intuition:

You can decompose $384=2^7·3$. If you divide by $48=2^4·3$ you are left with $2^3$. This means that the other number cannot have more $2$s than the ones from $48$ in its prime decomposition, or otherwise the $\gcd$ with $384$ would be greater. Therefore you can multiply $48$ by $1$; not $2$; $3$; $5$; not by $6$ since it would be multiplying by $2$ too; $7$; not $8$, and we have to stop there because $48·9>384$.

So there are four solutions: $48·1=48$; $48·3=144$; $48·5=240$; $48·7=336$.

Comment: Looks good. But you listed 4 solutions, not 3!

Comment: You're right, my bad!